# using jquery how to search data in html table

Tags: jquery

i want to display entire row (but the search opertion could be done in a particular column(td)).

by using this /**

```
$(function () {
  $('input#searchCode').quicksearch('table#employeeTable tbody tr',{

  });
 });
```

*/

i can search a text in entire row.but i dont know to search in a specified column and display entire row...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

try [this plugin](http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-column-filters/) out.  looks pretty painless.

Answer (score 0):

use `'selector': 'td:eq(3)'` for every 4th td...

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ETGg/) ( note that in my demo, 1st colum is a <th>, so your search will be in IP)